# Push sharp ios notification issue working before few days but now not working yet

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

**I had issue to send notification to IOS.**

**I used below code for send notification to IOS device:**

```
var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../../Resources/xxxxxxxxx-2015.p12"));
push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "xxxxxxxx"));
push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                          .ForDeviceToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                          .WithAlert("Hello World!")
                          .WithBadge(7)
                          .WithSound("sound.caf"));
```

#### I did same code in past it's work like pretty but now it's give me error as below

> Failure: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> Exception of type 'PushSharp.Apple.NotificationFailureException' was thrown**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be an problem with the PushSharp library you are using: [Failure PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> Exception of type 'PushSharp.Apple.NotificationFailureException' was thrown](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/510)

Comment: @Tor-Erik Yes, you are right. I find https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/510 issue on this thread, i also post my comment on github. **But strange thing is that before few days ago it's working, now it's give an error. So, I can't find from where problem from Push sharp Library or from Apple.**

Comment: @smoothersillent I had the same issue a month ago. So yes, there was an issue with the PushSharp library you are using. So try using the updated library from here [Redth PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) that has some modifications. So compile it and use the library which should work.

Comment: @VishalSuthar I had tried with latest version but there is still same issue.